# backgridjs model filter not hiding non-matched rows

Tags: jquery, backgrid

I've tried asking this question in the backgridjs github issues forum as well, but I know @wyuenho is a busy guy and this is somewhat of an urgent matter.

http://ap_gee.ig_te.ms/i_eapis/portal/sessions/example_broken.php [url obfuscated]

Here is an example of a backgridjs implementation of some upcoming event sessions. As you can see, client-side pagination is working perfectly. What is not, however, is the search functionality. If you begin typing into the filter box, you'll notice that backgrid properly rearranges the matching results to the top of the list, but it does *not* hide the non-matches as it is expected to.

While originally I thought this was a one-off issue, I've noticed similar behavior in an unrelated auto-complete plugin for jQuery that I'm using elsewhere. This suggests to me that the the culprit is either A) the jQuery version (though I've tried several), or B) something to do with the bootstrap CSS or one of the other javascript libraries I've got included. I just can't seem to pare down WHAT is causing the problem, and would appreciate more sets of eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh.

Didn't even think to check the VERSION of file.

I was using version 1.2.2 of the backgrid-paginator.js file (via cloudflare CDN). Current version is 1.3.2, which fixes this problem:

http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone-pageable/1.3.2/backbone-pageable.min.js